# Login with 'sa' is working from Sql Server Management Studio, but failing from .Net application

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, authentication, c#-3.0

I am trying to connect the sql server database using 'sa' from my .Net windows application. I am getting the error: Cannot opend . Login failed for sa for . But I am able to connect to same database from Sql Server Management Studio. Please provide me the fix.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the SQL Server Management Studio on the same computer that you have your Visual Studio, if yes, then check your connection string, it should be like below:

Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=**"Password"**;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=**"Username"**;Initial Catalog=**"Initial Database"**;Data Source=**"Server IP"**

If the management studio is not on the Server, then it might be because of a Windows Firewall issue, check the below URL for how to change the firewall settings:

[***Cannot Login To SQL Server From Network***](http://www.it-archives.com/Articles/CannotLogintoSQLServerFromNetwork.aspx)